# Create stage with powershell on azure devops release

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, scripting

powershell script for create stage in release on azure devops
the error stay same on every change I try for fix it , to set null to set empty hash @(), same...

```
Error: 
Invoke-WebRequest : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402877: Pre-approvals or post-approvals in stage 'TestAvo' are empty. Specify approvals and try 
again.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data","typeKey":"InvalidRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

I tried everything including setting them to NULL, but I kept getting the same error

script:

```
#--------------------------------------------Configuration--------------------------------------------
$global:token = "X"
$global:token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$global:header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
$organization = 'X'
$project = 'X'
$definitionID = 1
$stageName = 'TestAvo'

#------------------------------------------------Functions------------------------------------------------

function Get_Release ($definitionID){
    $URI = 'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/'+$organization+'/'+$project+'/_apis/release/definitions/'+$definitionID+'?api-version=6.0'
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $URI -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -ErrorAction Stop
    if ($response.StatusCode -eq 200) {
        $Release = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
        # Add retention policy to stage
        foreach ($stage in $Release.environments) {
            if ($stage.name -eq $stageName) {
                $stage.retentionPolicy = @{
                    daysToKeep = 7
                    releasesToKeep = 3
                    retainBuild = "false"
                }
            }
        }
        return $Release
    } else {
        Write-Error "Failed to get release definition. Status code: $($response.StatusCode)"
        return $null
    }
}


function Export_Release($release){
    $output_name = $release.name
    $release = $release | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
    $release | Out-File ('C:\Temp\Releases\'+$output_name+'.txt')
    
}

function Invoke_Release($Release){

    $Release = $Release | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
    $URI = 'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/'+$organization+'/'+$project+'/_apis/release/definitions/'+$definitionID+'?api-version=6.0'
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI -Method PUT -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing -Body $Release -ContentType application/json -ErrorAction Stop
    if ($response.StatusCode -ne 200) {
        Write-Error "Failed to update release. Status code: $($response.StatusCode)"
    }
}

#------------------------------------------------Main------------------------------------------------

$Release = Get_Release $definitionID

if ($release) {
    # Check if stage already exists
    if ($release.environments | Where-Object {$_.name -eq $stageName}) {
        Write-Warning "Stage '$stageName' already exists."
    } else {
        # Create new stage
        $retention = @{
            daysToKeep = 7
            releasesToKeep = 3
            retainBuild = "false"
        }
        $newStage = @{
            name = $stageName
            rank = $release.environments.Count + 1
            retentionPolicy = $retention
            preDeployApprovals = @()
        }
        $release.environments += $newStage
        Invoke_Release $release
        Write-Host "Stage '$stageName' created successfully."
    }
}
```

Comment: SOmebody got same error message and found solution : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f6883654-c5b4-40fe-ad83-11a3f5f37a6b/unable-to-import-release-template-after-updated?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: not help to mee